# Save Date.now() to timestamp column but get date/time field value out of range

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

My project (NestJS with TypeScript) is using `TypeOrm` on PostgreSQL database.

My table has a column (in migration file):

```
new TableColumn({
   name: 'managed_at',
   type: 'timestamp',
   isNullable: true,
 }),
```

Associated field in entity class:

```
  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
  managedAt: Date | null;
```

I would like the column `managed_at` holds value of date and time.

If I save a data to the table with:

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
...
// repo is the Repository of typeorm
repo.update(
    { managedAt: Date.now() }
  );
```

I get error:

```
 QueryFailedError: date/time field value out of range: "1651495656811"
```

How to solve this problem that using Date.now() and hold value of data and time?

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
...
// repo is the Repository of typeorm
repo.update(
    { managedAt: new Date() }
  );
```

Change Date.now() -> new Date().
You need to save Date type data to column in timestamp type.

Btw, you can add this in your entity class.
It will update column before update data.

```
  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateManagedAt(): void {
    this.managedAt = new Date();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC, as per documentation here [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Whereas valid input for the time stamp types consists of the concatenation of a date and a time, followed by an optional time zone (if you are using timestamptz type instead of timestamp type), followed by an optional AD or BC. (Alternatively, AD/BC can appear before the time zone, but this is not the preferred ordering.
You can read more about Date/Time types in pgSQL [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

In your case, you can do it like this

```
    repo.update({ managedAt: (new Date()).toISOString() });
```

You'd use toISOString for sharing a date with another machine or process.